# extracting row specified by a dictionary using pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a large dictionary where each key corresponds to a list. For example

```
dictionary = {'1':[391,183,117,193,971],'2':[8817,38103,6163,173],'3':[8173,137,984,9173]}
```

And I have a dataframe with 1837391 rows in total. My dataframe looks like as follows:

```
ID    start      end      name
1      29        120      Peter
2      130       200      Sarah
3      10        20       Nikki
```

Now I want to count all those rows where the values fall in the intervals as specified by **start** and **end** column for each of the key separately.

For example for key **1** 117,183,193 falls in the interval so it should return 3. Because 117 will be found in row 1 of my dataframe and 183 and 193 in row 2. How can I achieve that? Insights will be appreciated.

Comment: Need a sample input and expected output as a dataframe.

Comment: For the example input dataframe, a value such as 125 should not be counted, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use dict comprehension

```
{
    k: sum(1 for i in v if i >= df.start.min() and i <= df.end.max())
    for k, v in dictionary.items()
}
```

Output

```
{'1': 3, '2': 1, '3': 1}
```